# Changing square number into text "Chosen" when clicking and back to number when clicking again

Tags: jquery, text, numbers

I have grid/crisscross which contains numbers. When I click the square, the number in the square should change into text "Chosen". When I click again another square, the text should turn back into the number which it was originally. How could I turn it back to the number it was originally?

I should use jQuery. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("td").click(function () {
                $("td").text("Chosen");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: deeppink;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

     
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="font-size:20px">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing its content, just apply a class to it which makes it display the desired text. This way you don't have to worry about storing the value somewhere for when you want to revert it.

```
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    // remove .chosen class from all tds
    $('td').removeClass("chosen")
    // add it to clicked one
    $(this).addClass("chosen");
  });
});
```

The simplest method to not display an elements's contents and replace it with some text is:

```
element {
  visibility: hidden;
}
element:before {
  visibility: visible;
  contents: 'The replacement content'
}
```

But trouble is `:before` and `:after` don't play nice with table elements, so we need a small script that grabs the contents of each `td` and wraps them in a `<span>` when the page loads, so we can apply the above method to the `<span>` element:

```js
$("td").each(function(){
  $(this).html($('<span />', {
    html: $(this).html()
  }))
})
```

Let's see if it works:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $('td').removeClass("chosen")
    $(this).addClass("chosen");
  }).each(function() {
    $(this).html($('<span />', {
      html: $(this).html()
    }))
  })
});
```

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: deeppink;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.chosen span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.chosen span:before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: 'Chosen'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="font-size:20px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```